# my arrows to change images aren´t working on internet explorer (unslider plugin)

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-plugins, unslider

Im trying to use unslider jQuery plugin but Im having one issue.

Unslider is already working fine, but my arrows to change images aren´t working on internet explorer.

On google chrome is working perfectly.

Do you see why this can be happening?

I have my example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/bdmU4/7/

This is my jQuery script:

```
var unslider = $('.banner').unslider({
        speed: 3000,               
        delay: 10000,      
        pause: true,     
        keys: true,       
        dots: true ,     
    });

    $('.unslider-arrow').click(function() {
        var fn = this.className.split(' ')[1];
        event.preventDefault();

        unslider.data('unslider')[fn]();
    });
```

Strangly, like this : http://jsfiddle.net/bdmU4/9/ works on IE, but I have strange weird effects, like random speeds, delay and sometimes direction of the exchange of images changes. I think that is because in this last fiddle I have two ocurrences of unslider declaration.

Comment: Which version of IE? I’ve tested IE11, back to IE8 and they work when clicking the dots, the next/prev links and using the arrow keys.

Comment: What fiddle you tested David Storey? My first or second?

Comment: first http://jsfiddle.net/bdmU4/7/

Comment: I dont understand, my first fiddle dont work for me on IE10...